# SD Card Reader not working

Tags: mount, sd-card

Yeah, I am very new to Linux, so please, if you have a solution for me, make it very descriptive cause I have no idea how to use this thing now.

It shows my card in the file manager, but when I click on it to view the files an error comes up that says this.

> Error mounting /dev/mmcblk1p1 at /media/trotamundos/9C33-6BBD:
>   Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/mmcblk1p1" "/media/trotamundos/9C33-6BBD"' exited with non-zero
>   exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

Anyone have any suggestions of what to try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`exFAT` is a proprietary FS and the drivers for it are not installed in Ubuntu by default, but can be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

Then probably reboot and try it again. If you still cannot use it then type

```
lspci -v
```

and copy the result back here. You might need a driver for the reader to work right as well.

Comment: Glad I could help.